# Select yesterday date in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have one table with three columns, ID, SETTLE_DATE_TIME, STATUS . I trying to select the data which the `SETTLE_DATE_TIME` is yesterday and the STATUS is 'E'.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM rev_acq_edcbatch 
 WHERE EDCBATCH_STATUS='E' 
   AND EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

No data was retrieved but I have a data which settle date time is `2017-01-26 16:28:50.000` and status is E.

Comment: What is the exact type of the field SETTLE_DATE_TIME ? date + time? timestamp? date only?

Comment: @Redlab timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, where `EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME` has proper date time format of sql.

```sql
SELECT * FROM rev_acq_edcbatch 
WHERE DATE(EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME) = CURDATE() - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SUBDATE` function with `current_date`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rev_acq_edcbatch 
WHERE EDCBATCH_STATUS='E' 
AND EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME = subdate(current_date, 1)
```

Use the `SUBDATE` function with `NOW()` if `EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME` is a timestamp.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rev_acq_edcbatch 
WHERE EDCBATCH_STATUS='E' 
AND EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME = subdate(NOW(), 1)
```

Comment: No working.....

Comment: What data type is `EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME`

Comment: timestamp......

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM rev_acq_edcbatch
WHERE EDCBATCH_STATUS='E' 
  AND DATE(EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME) = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()));
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GETDATE()))' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT * FROM rev_acq_edcbatch where EDCBATCH_STATUS='E' AND EDCBATCH_SETTLE_DATETIME = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ;
```

Comment: No working.....